# Extract mobile number from string using regex

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to extract mobile number from a string.
Example string is `"Hi, Your Mobile no. is: 9876499321."`

Now I want to extract "9876499321" from the string. My main string can have +919876499321 or 919876499321 or 09876499321 inside the string along with other words. How to achieve this?

Rules I want:

1. First of all remove all "-"
2. Then extract number that can range from 10 digit to 14 digit (inclusive)

I have tried this:

```
String myregex = "^\\d{10}$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myregex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

I am not able to find any match.

Comment: Try `"\\d{10}\\b"` to get the last 10 digits of a standalone number. What is the actual rule here?

Comment: WHAT IF I WANT TO REMOVE ANY "-" FROM NUMBER (EX. 91-923223) ?

Comment: What if you provide all the possible cases/explain the exact number of rules to extract the text you want?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  have edited my question

Comment: Try 1) `Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr.replace("-", ""))` and 2) `"\\b\\d{10,14}\\b"` or `"(?<!\\d)\\d{10,14}(?!\\d)"` regex.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks !! Works perfectly.

Comment: Posted an answer with a demo and explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may remove all hyphens before passing the string to `pattern.matcher` and then match standalone numbers of 10 to 14 digits:

```
String inputStr = "Hi, Your Mobile no. is: 9876499321. Also, +919876499321 or 919876499321 or 09-876499321.";   
String myregex = "(?<!\\d)\\d{10,14}(?!\\d)";
// Or String myregex = "\\b\\d{10,14}\\b";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(myregex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(inputStr.replace("-", ""));

while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/AzqLuG), output:

```
9876499321
919876499321
919876499321
09876499321
```

The `(?<!\d)\d{10,14}(?!\d)` pattern matches 10 to 14 digits only if they are not enclosed with other digits.

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the last 10 digits of a 10+ digit string, you can do the following:

`String myregex = "^.*(\\d{10})([^\\d].*|$)";`

And use `matcher.group(0)` instead of `matcher.group()`.